# Need to pass values in associative array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to achieve is to get all products name from page its position and than store it in an array which than I can use in next part of the code. Here is that I have done so far

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">     </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var i = 1;
$(".product-name").each(function() {
    var pnameforostock = $(this).text();
    var positionp = i++;
                    alert(pnameforostock);

    });

  });
 </script>    
 <body>
 <li class="item">

            <a href="product1.php" title="Sample Product Name" class="product-image">
                                 <span class="sale-item">Sale!</span>
                                <div class="cat-mouseover"></div>
                <img src="/images/product1.png" alt="Sample Product Name"></a>
            <h2 class="product-name"><a href="product1.php" title="Sample Product Name">Sample Product Name</a></h2>
<div class="price-box">

                <p class="old-price">
            <span class="price-label">For:</span>
            <span class="price" id="old-price-426">
                &nbsp;199,-                </span>
        </p>

                    <p class="special-price">
            <span class="price-label"></span>
            <span class="price" id="product-price-426">
                Now&nbsp;139,-                </span>
        </p>


    </div>
                            <div class="actions">
                                        <button type="button" title="Buy Now" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.google.com/')"><span><span>Buy</span></span></button>     
                                </div>
        </li>

 <li class="item">

            <a href="product1.php" title="Sample Product Name" class="product-image">
                                 <span class="sale-item">Sale!</span>
                                <div class="cat-mouseover"></div>
                <img src="/images/product1.png" alt="Sample Product Name"></a>
            <h2 class="product-name"><a href="product1.php" title="Sample Product Name">Sample Product Name 2</a></h2>
<div class="price-box">

                <p class="old-price">
            <span class="price-label">For:</span>
            <span class="price" id="old-price-426">
                &nbsp;199,-                </span>
        </p>

                    <p class="special-price">
            <span class="price-label"></span>
            <span class="price" id="product-price-426">
                Now&nbsp;139,-                </span>
        </p>


    </div>

                            <div class="actions">
                                        <button type="button" title="Buy Now" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy52aXRhLm5vLw,,/product/426/')"><span><span>Buy</span></span></button>
                                </div>
        </li>

        </body>
 </html>
```

From the above jquery code I am able to get the product names but not able to place them in array so that it will look something like this

**name: product1, name: product2**

I tried a lot to get some results in array but no success. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want an array of objects (JS doesn't have associative arrays)

```
var products = $(".product-name a").map(function() {
    return { name: $(this).text() }
}).get();
```

`.map` reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Comment: thank you @tymeJV for the code, but I am not able to get the output from this code. I replaced my jquery code with your and no success. Can you please guide.